# 'Company' and 'Person': threat them similar... but gives problems when creating forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, polymorphic-associations

Our company can have a contract with a person and a company.

So the responsible 'party' of a contract, can be both a person and a company.

I have setup a model where:

### ---

Contract ------ person
             |
             -- company

class Contract < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :party, :polymorphic => true
end

class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  has_many :contracts, :as => :party
end

class Organization < Party
end

class Person < Party
end

### ---

What I want to be able to do is have a form "new contract" and in the field "contract with" I'd like to have a dropdown box of all known people and companies.

### ---

In the end: I'm willing to change my model and ideas... but the behaviour that should remain is that a contract can be closed with both a person and a company. Any suggestion is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You could fill your select values with a string containing both class and id (i.e. ), which you then process in either the model or controller.